# Is my laptop done?

Tags: laptop, bios

..hi. Today I played with my BIOS, applied settings and then things gone wrong. Display isnt turning on, external monitor as well, when I have RAM installed onto the baord, it restarts itself multiple times till it establishes and keeps on, removig cmos and any power for 20 mins didnt work, holding F8, or even F8 + Shift while booting had no effect, removing battery and power cable and holding power button for 60 secs didnt work... Please... Help me, I have Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q with BIOS 6.80 and i5 3210M + 8GB ram... Please.. I dont have budget for new laptop

Edit: motherboard still can detect battery and powers hard drives as well CPU gets hot + any usb device turns on for maybe a second and turns off then

- i think i have disabled internal graphics device

Comment: Can you start in BIOS?  Depends on the machine but usually pressing F1 repeatedly will get into BIOS.  If so, reset BIOS to defaults, save and restart. Any luck with this process?

Comment: @John my display isnt turning on

Comment: I think you must have a hardware problem. I missed the External Monitor sentence - sorry. I think you have a motherboard issue at this point.

Comment: It has to be BIOS, everything started back to then I need to reset it somehow or something

Comment: If you have no monitor, there is not much chance to reset BIOS. You need to see what you are doing and follow the screen prompts to reset.  Get the Toshiba BIOS on a bootable USB key and see if that will start a BIOS procedure to allow you to see

Comment: @John the external monitor detects the laptop to be connected, but is just blank

Comment: BIOS does not need any video driver, so your symptoms do indicate a hardware problem

Comment: @John then BIOS might be the problem, what can I do with it, can I reinstall it or something?

Comment: That is a bit strange because (a) you meed to be able to see and (b) BIOS do not need much for display and does not disable (turn off) the display.

Comment: What about unplugging main and CMIS battery to see if you can default  CMOS to factory?

Comment: @davidgo as i mentioned, already tried to unplug cmos and wait